# INSERT statement conflicted with foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having issue with an assignment I'm working on right now. The question is:

Write an INSERT statement that adds this row to the `Products` table:

- ProductID: The next automatically generated ID
- CategoryID: 4
- ProductCode: dgx_640
- ProductName: Yamaha DGX 640 88-Key Digital Piano
- Description: Long description to come.
- ListPrice: 799.99
- DiscountPercent: 0
- DateAdded: Today’s date/time.

Use a column list for this statement.

And the answer I came up with is:

```
INSERT INTO Products(CategoryID, ProductCode, ProductName, Description, ListPrice, DiscountPercent, DateAdded)
VALUES (4, 'dgx_640', 'Yamaha DGX 640 88-Key Digital Piano', 'Long description to come.', 799.99, 0, SYSDATETIME())
```

But when I try to execute it, an error comes up saying

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Products__Catego__3B75D760". The conflict occurred in database "MyGuitarShop", table "dbo.Categories", column 'CategoryID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the question? The insert statement is trying to insert a row, that has a value that references another table, where a corresponding row does not exist. Judging by the name of the constraint, it would be the category value referencing an existing category in the category table. Have you checked that the category table has a row with CategoryID of 4?

Answer (score 4):

The error is very clear - you're trying to insert a value into the `CategoryID` column of `Products` which causes a violation of the foreign key constraint to the category table.

This means: you're trying to insert a value (`4`) into `Products.CategoryID` which **does not exist** in the `Category` table. The foreign key constraint's job is to **prevent exactly this case** - it will **not** allow you to do this - for good reason.

So basically: you need to ensure that the values you're inserting into foreign key columns **do exist** in the referenced table (`Category`) before you do the `INSERT`.

Comment: I have never done this but I have to say "The error is very clear" just rubs me the wrong way as it feels very condescending. The error is not clear to me and (I assume) to the OP otherwise this post would probably not exist. That said the rest of your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[image]The reference may not need to be enforced.

**Make a new Database Diagram and add your two tables.  Right click the connection line going between them, choose properties.
Where it says 'Enforce Foreign Key Constraint' change it to No.
This fixed the issue for me.**

It is also possible that the number you're trying to insert and reference is an auto number row as a primary key in the connected table.  I can only assume this can cause as issue, vs having the column be it's own editable column value.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to insert a value in the foreign key that doesn't exist in the table it reference, in you'r case it's the `CategoryID`.
to solve this you need to insert number 4 in the `CategoryID` column in the table `catego` first